# How To find a word and replace with changing pattern

Tags: vim, notepad++, regex, gvim, sublime-text-2

I have a text like the following:

```
case "UID":
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(objDataReader["XYZ"]))
{
    objQualitativeAssessmentBiz.XYZ = objDataReader["XYZ"].ToString();
}
break;
case "GeneratedChaseId":
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(objDataReader["XYZ"]))
{
    objQualitativeAssessmentBiz.XYZ = objDataReader["XYZ"].ToString();
}
break;
```

Now I want to replace each XYZ with the word that comes after the word: case. So the replaced text would look like this:

```
case "UID":
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(objDataReader["UID"]))
{
    objQualitativeAssessmentBiz.UID = objDataReader["UID"].ToString();
}
break;
case "GeneratedChaseId":
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(objDataReader["GeneratedChaseId"]))
{
    objQualitativeAssessmentBiz.GeneratedChaseId = objDataReader["GeneratedChaseId"].ToString();
}
break;
```

Is there any suitable editor that can perform this task? If so, then how?

Comment: If you work on unix/linux, `awk` would be your best tool for this. Could anyone working on unix or linux add an answer based on `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vim's record functionality. You can read up on it [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Recording_keys_for_repeated_jobs).

As for your code snippet, please try the following in your vim/vi editor:

1. First select the word "case" by placing the cursor over the word and hitting *
2. Now go to the top of the file --> gg
3. Turn on recording --> qa
4. Now run the following key sequence in command mode.

   ```
   n w w yw j $ b b P l dw b yw j j 0 w w p l dw i <space> <esc> b yw w w w w P dw dw
   ```
5. Turn off recording --> q. Your recording has been saved under the key "a" (because you turned it on by running qa)
6. Now you can run this recording as many times as you want. So if you want to have it applied to your entire file run it as many times as the total number of case statements. For 10 case statements run --> 10@a.

Comment: Add some explanation on the key sequence and you get my up-vote

Comment: @DirkHorsten There's really no point adding an explanation for the key sequence. This sequence is not a set recipe for thiss kind of problems but simply a sequence of vim commands to move the cursor and copy-paste words which will only work for the OP's code snippet.

Comment: @DirkHorsten [here](http://vim.rtorr.com/) is a vim cheat sheet for your reference.

Comment: OK, I see, you are counting on an identical structure of every case-break block